# Can not restart the httpd.service

Tags: linux, apache-httpd

I use the systemctl to restart the httpd, but failed:

```
[root@controller ~]# systemctl restart httpd.service
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

And I status it, get the below information:

```
   [root@controller ~]# systemctl status httpd.service
   httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-07-12 15:48:35 CST; 11s ago
         Docs: man:httpd(8)
               man:apachectl(8)
      Process: 10093 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      Process: 10091 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Main PID: 10091 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

    Jul 12 15:48:35 controller httpd[10091]: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:5000
    Jul 12 15:48:35 controller httpd[10091]: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:5000
    Jul 12 15:48:35 controller httpd[10091]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
    Jul 12 15:48:35 controller httpd[10091]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
    Jul 12 15:48:35 controller systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    Jul 12 15:48:35 controller kill[10093]: kill: cannot find process ""
    Jul 12 15:48:35 controller systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
    Jul 12 15:48:35 controller systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
    Jul 12 15:48:35 controller systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
    Jul 12 15:48:35 controller systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
```

I use the `journalctl -xe`:

```
root@controller httpd]# journalctl -xe
Jul 12 16:06:43 controller systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jul 12 16:06:43 controller systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Jul 12 16:06:43 controller polkitd[1056]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:10390:2078277 (system bus name :1.159, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authent
Jul 12 16:06:53 controller polkitd[1056]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:10405:2079366 (system bus name :1.160 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], ob
Jul 12 16:06:53 controller systemd[1]: Reloading.
Jul 12 16:06:53 controller systemd[1]: [/usr/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service:43] Unknown lvalue 'MemoryDenyWriteExecute' in section 'Service'
Jul 12 16:06:53 controller systemd[1]: Configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/system/auditd.service is marked world-inaccessible. This has no effect as configuration data is accessib
Jul 12 16:06:54 controller systemd[1]: Configuration file /usr/lib/systemd/system/wpa_supplicant.service is marked executable. Please remove executable permission bits. Proceeding
Jul 12 16:06:54 controller polkitd[1056]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:10405:2079366 (system bus name :1.160, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authent
Jul 12 16:06:55 controller polkitd[1056]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:10421:2079560 (system bus name :1.161 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], ob
Jul 12 16:06:55 controller systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has begun starting up.
Jul 12 16:06:55 controller httpd[10426]: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:5000
Jul 12 16:06:55 controller httpd[10426]: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:5000
Jul 12 16:06:55 controller httpd[10426]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Jul 12 16:06:55 controller httpd[10426]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jul 12 16:06:55 controller systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 12 16:06:55 controller kill[10428]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jul 12 16:06:55 controller systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jul 12 16:06:55 controller systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
-- Subject: Unit httpd.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit httpd.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Jul 12 16:06:55 controller systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jul 12 16:06:55 controller systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Jul 12 16:06:55 controller polkitd[1056]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:10421:2079560 (system bus name :1.161, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authent
lines 1377-1410/1410 (END)
```

And in the `/var/log/httpd/` directory, there is no logs here.

---

**EDIT-1**

And I find the `5000` port, get the below information:

```
[root@controller selinux]# netstat | grep 5000
[root@controller selinux]#
```

---

**EDIT-2**

In the `/var/www/` directory:

```
[root@controller www]# ls
cgi-bin  html
```

both the cgi-bin and html is empty.

---

**EDIT-3**

the `httpd.conf` file contents under the `/etc/httpd/conf/`:

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"

Listen 80

Include conf.modules.d/*.conf

User apache
Group apache

ServerAdmin root@localhost


ServerName controller

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>


DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"


<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    # Allow open access:
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# Further relax access to the default document root:
<Directory "/var/www/html">

    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>


<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>

    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>


<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule mime_module>

    TypesConfig /etc/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mime_magic_module>

    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>


EnableSendfile on

IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

---

**EDIT-4**

The `/var/log/httpd` limits is below:

```
[root@controller system]# ll -d /var/log/httpd
drwx------. 2 root root 6 Nov 20  2015 /var/log/httpd
```

---

**EDIT-5**

I check the port 5000:

```
[root@controller httpd]# ps -aux | grep 5000
rabbitmq   8710  0.9  0.9 2348444 78620 ?       Ssl  14:39   1:25 /usr/lib64/erlang/erts-7.3.1.2/bin/beam.smp -W w -A 64 -P 1048576 -t 5000000 -stbt db -K true -- -root /usr/lib64/erlang -progname erl -- -home /var/lib/rabbitmq -- -pa /usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-3.6.5/ebin -noshell -noinput -s rabbit boot -sname rabbit@controller -boot start_sasl -config /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq -kernel inet_default_connect_options [{nodelay,true}] -sasl errlog_type error -sasl sasl_error_logger false -rabbit error_logger {file,"/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@controller.log"} -rabbit sasl_error_logger {file,"/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@controller-sasl.log"} -rabbit enabled_plugins_file "/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins" -rabbit plugins_dir "/usr/lib/rabbitmq/lib/rabbitmq_server-3.6.5/plugins" -rabbit plugins_expand_dir "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@controller-plugins-expand" -os_mon start_cpu_sup false -os_mon start_disksup false -os_mon start_memsup false -mnesia dir "/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@controller" -kernel inet_dist_listen_min 25672 -kernel inet_dist_listen_max 25672
root      11787  0.0  0.0 112644   952 pts/1    S+   17:13   0:00 grep --color=auto 5000
```

---

**EDIT-6**

I use the semanage to add the port 5000:

```
[root@controller httpd]# semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 5000
ValueError: Port tcp/5000 already defined
```

---

**EDIT-7**

In the directory `/usr/lib/systemd/system/`, there is httpd.service here:

```
[root@controller system]# pwd
/usr/lib/systemd/system
[root@controller system]# ls | grep http
httpd.service
```

Comment: @jx12345 what do yuo mean? my httpd is combined with the openstack's keystone, and memcached.

Comment: edit 3 worked for me.. Thanks.. I had to remove one line "IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
"  at the last.. which i added following "https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-centos-8" method  .. is that OKAY?

Answer (score 3):

This problem is caused due to `SELinux` not allowing apache to connect on port `5000`

This is what `systemctl status httpd.service` is showing you:

```
Jul 12 15:48:35 controller httpd[10091]: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:5000
Jul 12 15:48:35 controller httpd[10091]: (13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:5000
```

To fix this you need to add port `5000` to `http_port_t` type definition as follow:

```
semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 5000
```

Since port `5000` has already been defined, you need to use `-m`. To do so, use

```
semanage port -m -t http_port_t -p tcp 5000
```

Note!
If port `5000` is already assigned to another service type definition you won't be able to assign this port to `http_port_t` type definition. In other words, you'd need to use another port since SELinux policy won't allow it.

Comment: But I was disabled the selinux in the config file:`SELINUX=disabled
`

Comment: If I disabled the selinux, so the `-bash: semanage: command not found` ?

Comment: @lustre disabling SELinux is a bad idea. It was not designed to be disabled. Please enable it, run the above command and update your question. Show us your `httpd.conf` file, relevant directives, logs etc. Permissions of `/var/log/httpd` and so on.

Comment: I am use this as develop environment so I close the SELINUX, my httpd.conf is in the Edit-3.

Comment: the EDIT-5 maybe help.

Comment: @lustre did you change the systemd system files? `ps aux | grep 5000` doesn't check for the port, it rather greps for a process id that "might" be include `5000` in it. What does `lsof -i :5000` tell you. While your `httpd.conf` file shows `LIsten 80` how is it that the logs are indicating that apache wants to connect on port `5000`?

Comment: the `lsof -i :5000` shows nothing, and I use your method in the answer, get the edit-6.

Comment: @lustre as I mention in my answer, you need to use a port that's not assigned to a service definition type. If you `really` want to use this port, then see an update in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I saw your environment is development, not production.

So set the selinux permissive model can be help.

Follow the steps:

```
# getenforce
# setenforce 0   // there will print `Permissive`
# systemctl start  httpd.service
```

Check it :

```
systemctl status  httpd.service
```

Comment: This works for me, but as val0x00ff said, we should enable the selinux, how to do with that?

Comment: You save my day! I was deleted all logs folder (bad idea)...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I added an ssl conf under `/etc/httpd/conf.d` by copying the `ssl.conf`, but leaving the original behind.

By moving it to `ssl.conf.bak` the error went away.